# Boosting the relevance of a field, with the value of another (numerical)

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

I am developing a platform, where users are organizing items in collections. Each of the collections can be followed by users. Those collections  are afterwards indexed by Solr, and made searchable. I realized that if I use a very simple kind of boosting towards the collection name (and the names of the items within), the results I get mostly are collections with a very small number of items (which is normal, because the pool of words is much smaller => the relevance higher). Of course, this is not exactly what I want.

What I want is to be able to boost the collection name with another field that I  also index in Solr, called numItems.

In other words, instead of `name:query^3`, to get something like `name:query^numItems`, or even better `name:"query"^(numItems*numFollowers)`

Is this possible? Is this the only option? The only other thing that comes to mind is to try to sort the results by the same paramaters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to disable length normalization for your main field, via the `omitNorms` field property in schema.xml.

If you still need to fine tune the scoring, you can use a function query. See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ) for more information, but a short example of a query string that uses a simple boost like you describe above would be:

```
q={!boost b=(numItems*numFollowers)}query
```

Comment: I think that will work. I will give it a try tomorrow to see if it helps and then I will mark it as the accepted answer